# Load of Combo Box does not display selected value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a combo box on a form - "`cboCurPartNum`".  When I go to open the form and the existing data populates the form, my combo box does not display the value stored in SQL server.

How can I get my Combo Box to display the value in my record?

What is happening here is the form is opened in the "Modify Engineering Order" mode.  So, the statement

```
public EngOrd engord;
```

contains the data for the engineering order that is being opened.

The issue is where `"addEngOrd" = false` in the "Modify Engineering Order" section.  You will see there the method "`PutNewEngOrd()`" is called and the `newEngOrd` object gets assigned the existing values of the engineering order opened.

My problem is with the combo box "cboCurPartNum" which has the following set:

```
Data Source - partBindingSource
Display Member - PartNumber
Value Member - PartNumber
Selected Value - engOrderBindingSource - CurPartNum
```

This combo box should have the partnumber in "newEngOrd" assigned, because "`engordBindingSource.Add(newEngOrd);`" gets called after "`PutNewEngOrd()`" was run.

Why doesn't my part number display in the combo box?  The part number is stored in the database.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class frmEngOrdAddModify : Form
{
    public frmEngOrdAddModify()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    public bool addEngOrd;  //indicates if adding to the form or not
    public EngOrd engord; //data from the frmEngOrd (old eng order)
    private EngOrd newEngOrd;  //new data we are capturing here (new eng ord)


    private void frmEngOrdAddModify_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.LoadComboBoxes();           

        if (addEngOrd)
        {
            this.Text = "Add Engineering Order";
            newEngOrd = new EngOrd();
            engordBindingSource.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            this.Text = "Modify Engineering Order";
            newEngOrd = new EngOrd();                
            this.PutNewEngOrd();
        }
        engordBindingSource.Add(newEngOrd);  //put the existing or a new EngOrd dataset with the binding source


    }

    private void LoadComboBoxes()
    {

        List<EngOrdType> engOrdTypeList;
        engOrdTypeList = EngOrdTypeDB.GetEngOrdType();
        cboEOFileType.DataSource = engOrdTypeList;
        cboEOFileType.SelectedIndex = -1;

        List<Customer> customerList;
        customerList = CustomerDB.GetCustomerTeamList();
        cboCustomer.DataSource = customerList;
        cboCustomer.SelectedIndex = -1;

        List<Part> partList;
        partList = PartDB.GetPartList();
        cboCurPartNum.DataSource = partList;            
        cboCurPartNum.SelectedIndex = -1;

        // with modify mode intially display the value passed in from engord
        if (addEngOrd == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("assign here " + engord.CurPartNum);
            cboCurPartNum.SelectedValue = engord.CurPartNum;
        }
    }

    private void PutNewEngOrd()
    {
        newEngOrd.EO = engord.EO;
        newEngOrd.EONum = engord.EONum;
        newEngOrd.FileType = engord.FileType;
        newEngOrd.JobNum = engord.JobNum;
        newEngOrd.QuoteNum = engord.QuoteNum;
        newEngOrd.CustID = engord.CustID;
        newEngOrd.CurPartNum = engord.CurPartNum;            

    }
```

}

This is the designer generated code for "cboCurPartNum"

```
this.cboCurPartNum.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", this.engordBindingSource, "CurPartNum", true));
this.cboCurPartNum.DataSource = this.partBindingSource;
this.cboCurPartNum.DisplayMember = "PartNumber";
this.cboCurPartNum.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
this.cboCurPartNum.FormattingEnabled = true;
this.cboCurPartNum.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(142, 23);
this.cboCurPartNum.Name = "cboCurPartNum";
this.cboCurPartNum.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(179, 21);
this.cboCurPartNum.TabIndex = 11;
this.cboCurPartNum.ValueMember = "PartNumber";
this.cboCurPartNum.SelectionChangeCommitted += new System.EventHandler(this.cboCurPartNum_SelectionChangeCommitted_1)
```

This is what I have now:
This is what I have now.  What do I need to the setting the SelectedValue?

```
        private void LoadComboBoxes()
    {

        List<EngOrdType> engOrdTypeList;
        engOrdTypeList = EngOrdTypeDB.GetEngOrdType();
        cboEOFileType.DataSource = engOrdTypeList;
        cboEOFileType.SelectedIndex = -1;

        List<Customer> customerList;
        customerList = CustomerDB.GetCustomerTeamList();
        cboCustomer.DataSource = customerList;
        cboCustomer.SelectedIndex = -1;
        //MessageBox.Show(cboCustomer.SelectedItem.ToString());
        //MessageBox.Show(cboCustomer.SelectedValue.ToString());

        List<Part> partList;
        partList = PartDB.GetPartList();
        cboCurPartNum.DataSource = partList;
        cboCurPartNum.SelectedIndex = -1;
        if (addEngOrd == false)
        {
            cboCurPartNum.SelectedItem = partList[1];

        }

    }
```

Comment: make sure that the DataSource is not Null or Empty. To be able to show the Selected Value in that combobox you should have filled the DataSource with the collection from which the SelectedItem is taken

Comment: The combo box has values from the datasource "partBindingSource".  The value stored in the database is a valid value in the datasource.

Comment: @Nancy Are you sure the data types of `CurPartNum` and `PartNumber` are the same? they should be the same. I supposed all the possible values of `CurPartNum` are contained in `PartNumber` column, if not that's the problem.

Comment: The data types are the same for CurPartNum and PartNumber.  The CurPartNum initially gets saved using one of the values from the partBindingSource.PartNumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cboCurPartNum.SelectedValue = /*Here syou should set an item of type "Part". For Example **partList[0]***/

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
      InitializeComponent();
      LoadComboboxes();
    }

    public void LoadComboboxes() {
        List<Part> partList = PartDB.GetPartList();
        cboCurPartNum.DataSource = partList;
        cboCurPartNum.SelectedIndex = -1;
        var addEngOrd = false;
        if (addEngOrd  == false) {
          //MessageBox.Show("assign here " + 1);
          cboCurPartNum.SelectedItem = partList[1];
        }
    }
  }
  public static class PartDB {
    static PartDB() {
      PartList = new List<Part> {
        new Part {
          One = 1,
          Two = "unos"
        },
        new Part {
          One = 2,
          Two = "duos"
        }
      };
    }

    private static readonly List<Part> PartList;
    public static List<Part> GetPartList() {
      return PartList;
    }
  }

  public class Part {
    public int One { get; set; }
    public string Two { get; set; }
  }
}
```

also, Make sure the DisplayMember is set to the Property which you want to see in combobox (see attachment)
[image]

Comment: for full solution write me :)

Comment: how do I write you?  I am new to this forum.  How do I set the SelectedValue?

Comment: I found the issue.  There were carriage returns in the data with partBindingSource.  This data was coming from another system.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you setting a DisplayMember property for yours ComboBoxes - is it in a Designer generated code? 
Try to set DisplayMember property programmaticly and recheck that DisplayMember value matches the name of Part class property needed to be displayed.

Comment: Additionally - do the other to ComboBoxes viewing the values? Is the problem shows only with cboCurPartNum ComboBox?

Comment: The other ComboBoxes are viewing the values.  A DisplayMember is being set in the designer generated code.

Comment: The problem is only with cboCurPartNum

Comment: What is the type of PartNumber property? How the getter for this property looks like?

Comment: private string partnumber; public string PartNumber{ get{ return partnumber;} set{ partnumber = value; } }

Comment: I know I have a value in CurPartNum for the engordBindingSource.  I checked by displaying it in a message box after engordBindingSource.Add(newEngOrd); is run

Comment: Do the Items adding to CB at all? Is the problem only with displaying values?

Comment: Set a break point after supposed binding of values are made and check CB.Items collection.